# Setting up Windows server 2022 to VPN server

Tags: networking, vpn, sql-server, azure, windows-server-2022

I'm trying to set up application and VPN connection on new Win Server 2022 like it's currently set up on old Win Server 2008 and I'm stuck...Basically I'm trying to mirror everything on Win Server 2022.

The guy who did that few years ago for a client is unreachable so I-m stuck with this problem...

Current test and production environment is (Servers are VMs on Azure, and I have access to everything):

```
- VPN Linux server on Azure (it uses OpenVPN)
- Win server 2008 (on Azure) and MSSQL database are connected to VPN server
- To connect to MSSQL locally or to connect to Win server via RD I have to be connected to VPN over OpenVPN
```

The things I did:

```
- Created new win server 2022 on Azure, set up IIS, users and stuff like that
- Made a backup of database and restored it on Win 2022 server
- Deployed application on IIS on new server (it works but it wont connect to database, I suppose because of VPN). 
- Application works though when I run frontend and backend locally and database is on new server, also only when I'm connected to VPN
```

This is the result and problems:

```
- I can connect to Win 2022 server via RemoteDesktop without connecting to OpenVPN
- I can connect to MSSQL database on new server from my computer only when connected to OpenVPN (why? I mean, It's supposed to be like that but I don't know why and how it did this automatically after i restored db on new server)

- I didn't find anything on VPN server that would tell me it allows access for old Win 2008 server (no IP address, or anything helpful)
- I didn't find anything on old Win 2008 server that would tell me that it can be only accessed through VPN server and that all traffic goes throug it.
- Application works though when I run frontend and backend locally and database is on new server, also only when I'm connected to VPN
```

All of the servers are in the same resource group in Azure if that matters (VPN, Win server 2008, Win server 2022)

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks